# error message of no suitable user-defined conversion

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <strings.h>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <list>

 int main(){

char buffer[32] = {0};
std::string temp;
std::string apend;
//memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

std::cout << "Text in: \n";
  fgets(buffer, 32, stdin);
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < strlen(buffer); ++j){
                if(buffer[i] == ' '){
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
                }
            }
        }

    for(int i=0; i < strlen(buffer); ++i){
        std::cout << buffer[i]; 
        temp += buffer[i];
    }

    reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter a new string: \n" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> apend;
    temp.append(apend);

    for(auto i = temp.begin(); i != temp.end(); ++i){
        std::cout << *i <<" ";
    }
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin();
```

> there is a error message saying no suitable user-defined conversion..., at 'ptr1 = temp.begin(), and i just can't deal with this problem. Can someone help take a look of my practice? Thanks!

```
return -1;

 }
```

Comment: You could remove almost all of that code and still show the problem. Don’t waste people’s time with all that noise.

Comment: You need to use the correct type. `decltype(temp)::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin();` - that is, `ptr1` is a `std::string::iterator`, not a `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Get rid of this.  And what is `<strings.h>`?  Also, there is no need for an inefficient, double nested `for` loop that repeatedly calls `strlen` to remove spaces from a string.

Comment: @TedLyngmo do you mean to correct syntax like 'std::vector<std::string>decltype(temp)::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin();'

Comment: N@Embeddeder No, exactly as I wrote it. The iterator is a `std::string::iterator` - nothing else.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "error: expected unqualified-id before 'auto'
   42 |        std::string::iterator::auto ptr1 = temp.begin();"

Comment: @Embeddeder I mean _exactly_ as I wrote it.

Comment: There's no `auto` in what I wrote above. I used `auto` in my answer below though. Both results in `ptr1` being a `std::string::iterator`.

Comment: The offending line is `std::vector<std::string>::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin()`.    This fails because `temp` is of type `std::string`, so `temp.begin()` has type `std::string::iterator`.   `std::string::iterator` is used to iterate over characters in `string`, and is a completely different thing from `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` which is used to iterate over `std::string`s in a `std::vector<string>`.    Since these two iterator types have different purposes (they iterate over different things) one cannot take the value of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct type which is `decltype(temp)::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin();` - that is, `ptr1` is a `std::string::iterator`, not a `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`. So for your snippet to compile, change

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator ptr1 = temp.begin();
```

to

```
auto ptr1 = temp.begin(); // ptr1 is a std::string::iterator
```

Comment: Thank you for being patient and explicit to answer me!

Comment: @Embeddeder No problem at all. Glad it helped and you're welcome!